# Stop commands in Microsoft Word ribbon from being "sticky"/remaining open?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, ribbon

I frequently type in Microsoft Word with the window minimized to take up half my screen. This compresses the ribbon such that, for example, the "Paragraph" grouping on the "Home" tab of the ribbon just says "Paragraph", and must be clicked on to access the commands in that group.

I have noticed in the last three months or so that when I open the "Paragraph" command grouping, or any of the other groupings, and select a command, I cannot continue typing until I click back in the document field. It is like the command grouping is a separate window, rather than integrated into the same window as the document.

This is infuriating. Is it a setting I can change?

[image: Screenshot of what happens when I open grouping and click on bulleted list]

(Screenshot of what happens when I open grouping and click on bulleted list)

I am using Microsoft 365 (on the Office support site I was told this was functionally the equivalent of Office 365 Family), Version 2006, Build 13001.20266; on a computer running Windows 10 Home version 1909, build 18363.959.